# Can sheet vinyl flooring be reused?

Tags: adhesive, vinyl-flooring, tape

Can vinyl sheet be reused?

If it has been fitted without adhesive I think obviously yes.

But what if you have used glue, if you pull the sheet up will the cushion or sheet be ripped/damaged such that you cannot reuse it?

Comment: Is this a padded room? Or a floor ? Just trying to get an idea of what you are asking maybe a photo of the sheet vinyl Would help.

Comment: @EdBeal I apologise Ed the questions isnt specific to any type of room and my first paragraph was irrelevant.  The question is generic and simply, if vinyl sheet has been glued or taped down with double sided tape, then the sheet is removed, will it be in good enough condition to be reused or not?

Comment: This is entirely a matter of opinion. In mine, some sheet vinyl isn't suitable for being installed _one_ time.

Comment: I did not realize your post was on the perimeter double sided tape . I have to agree with Alaska man especially with a padded vinyl the backing is very soft and I have ended up shaving it off the sub floor. If it was only stuck down at the very edge with glue or tape maybe you could cut several inches off each edge and re use it but if glued in the center I doubt it will be worth messing with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally have never seen vinyl pulled up, after being glued down, come up in a usable condition.

Even it it does not rip or tear i find the backing material separates and stays with the glue on the floor.

Comment: Yes and then a 8’ razor scraper becomes your best for end while shaving the floor.

Comment: @EdBeal YES, No fun. I can use all the for ends i can get.